# Ordering a list according to a target vector

Tags: r, list, sorting

Suppose I have a list:

```
  lst <- list(c(1,2), c(1,0), c(4,1), c(-7,11) )
```

I want to order this list according the elements of other vector. Assume the vector:

```
 v<- c(-1, 3, 0, -5)
```

Here 1st element of the list "lst" is related to 1st element of the vector "v" and similarly for the 2nd , 3rd and 4th. Since, -5<-1<0<3, the desired order of the list should be:

```
 list(c(-7,11), c(1,2), c(4,1), c(1,0))
```

It will be final output.

Comment: Something like this: `lst[order(v)]`? Check function order.

Comment: thanks dear...it works well

Answer (score 0):

This is not the one liner that exists somewhere but a workaround. Gives you the output you want. You can tweak the order ascending or descending if necessary.

```
lst <- list(c(1,2), c(1,0), c(4,1), c(-7,11) )
v <- c(-1, 3, 0, -5) 
new.order <- seq(1:length(v))
ref.frame <- data.frame(v,new.order)
ref.frame <- ref.frame[order(v),] 

> ref.frame
   v  new.order
4 -5          4
1 -1          1
3  0          3
2  3          2

lst <- lst[c(ref.frame$new.order)]

> lst
[[1]]
[1] -7 11

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 4 1

[[4]]
[1] 1 0
```